# How do I change the character encoding for a webpage in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, encoding, character-encoding

Google Chrome, like almost every web browser in recent memory, used to have an option to change the character encoding for the webpage being viewed by going to `Menu` › `Tools` › `Encoding` (or some similar location). This is extraordinarily useful in case the website misrepresents its encoding in its headers, or, failing to do so, Chrome mistakenly detects the encoding of the page.

However, it seems as though in recent versions of Chrome, this option to manually override the character encoding is… missing. Either missing, or moved somewhere very obscure, because I cannot find it anywhere.

I'm currently looking at a mojibake-filled webpage in what I presume should be Russian, which is entirely unreadable and unusable because Chrome is mistakenly rendering it with the wrong character encoding.

**How can I change the character encoding for a webpage in Google Chrome?**

**Edit:** For reference, I'm on `Version 55.0.2883.87 m`, and the encoding option is flat-out missing from the `Tools` menu:

[image]

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Unfortunately… a **Christmas-box** from Google Chrome: [*Chrome encoding options gone?*](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/2JIo6Yu7K-I):

> …
>
> **Chrome 55 has removed the Encoding menu** and Chrome will do
>   auto-encoding detection now:
>
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597488  - 
>   Remove encoding menu
>
> Manual encoding selection is not necessary any more as the new
>   encoding detector is turned on by default.
>
> **Manual encoding switching may be able to be done by use of Chrome
>   extensions**.
>
> *Marked as best answer by Kameron M - Community Manager*

Comment: *sigh~* Thanks for the information; rather a pity the new encoding detector is hot garbage.

Comment: Hum… I miss that option as well; I use this feature via [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) extension currently lacking better solution:(

Comment: This is a really sad turn of events. It seems that Chrome cannot correctly detect Shift-JIS encoding properly in all cases, which is becoming a hassle for me while doing research on Japanese webpages that haven't been updated in many years... At least Firefox lets me manually select Shift-JIS.

Comment: Unfortunately... many websites still mangle their own encodings.

Comment: What is even more awful, to be able to use these extensions on the saved pages you have to allow them "access to file:// urls"

Comment: Just adding my comment here *screaming* that whoever decided to remove this probably don't read anything other then ASCII, coming here after opening a txt file that isn't detected correctly, not to mention all pages that needs different encodings.

Comment: It seems Chrome is drifting towards what has been the IE behavior for year, making life of developers and users more and more miserable!

Comment: Nor can it detect the standard MS-DOS Cyrillic encoding, [code page 866](http://tortuga.angarsk.su/unrar/harmsd08/harms_1.txt). On the other hand, there is nothing wrong with an automatic encoding detection *per se*, as long as the good old manual selector is still available. But *Chrome* is becoming increasingly lamer-oriented—it has started targeing users that do not know what a character encoding is.

Comment: @Ant_222 yes, it's wrong recognized as Cyrillic encoding  [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) (tested in Chrome _IE tab extension_ as well as in Firefox).

Comment: @JosefZ: I wonder how it knew it was *Cyrillic* at all? Must be a bug...

Comment: Why some1 decide remove that simple and yet usable feature before actually having something better? WHY!?!?!?

Comment: This is rich. Found out today, that it can't even autodetect UTF-8.

Comment: Truly rich. I had to manually set UTF-8, on a page returning `content-type: text/plain`

Answer (score 40):

You can now use extensions. Here is an example
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/set-character-encoding/bpojelgakakmcfmjfilgdlmhefphglae

Comment: I tried to add a user-defined encoding (ISO-8859-1) in the settings of that addon without any luck. The "save" button does nothing.

Comment: @AndersLindén Try to close the option page then recheck the result

Comment: I have tried this extension, but unfortunatelly, it require to refresh the page. And it is not able to resend the POST data :-(

Comment: The huge and bloated *Chrome* needs an extension to do something that *all* the other browsers have done for decades, since the inception of internet.

Comment: This doesn't work for text documents.

Comment: @Rainb, It works. Here is an example
https://www.nta.go.jp/taxes/kids/hatten/txt/14.txt